MQTT and mosquitto with twincat can't connected
I'm writing here because I'm facing a problem with twincat and mqtt. I set up my broker (mosquitto 2.0.18)
I had fun before using the MQTT protocol with twincat to just connect the broker with another PC and send messages and receive them (so not the same IP + I used a WS) and it worked.
So now I wanted to make twincat send me messages but the fonction block (FB_IotMqttClient) doesn't want to connect between the broker and twincat.
I modified the conf of mosquitto (listener 1883 & allow_anonymous true)
I try to followed several tutorial (the last i check and rewrote. https://download-cdn.beckhoff.com/download/document/automation/twincat3/TF6701_TC3_IoT_Communication_MQTT_EN.pdf 13 to 15)
But it doesn't work, it doesn't want to connect and it doesn't seem to me that the function block is in error and I don't understand why. I'm a beginner in this area and I can't find my mistake. Thank you very much for the time you took to read and respond to this message.
The extended version of the results of fbMqttClient. ↓





With sHostName set to localhost this would be attempting to connect to itself - as the tutorial says "Alternatively, you can specify the IP address or host name of the system on which the message broker was installed". From the question it's not clear where the code is running relative to Mosquitto (but I'm guessing not the same machine?). .

thank you for your reply. so for this case it's local I try to do it little by little I started by doing a twincat project then configuring mosquitto and making it talk with another pc and now I'm trying to just send a message from twincat to my broker on the pc which runs mosquitto and the plc and when I have succeeded I will try to run the plc and mosquitto separately. This is to try to understand as best as possible

Which client is SPD? do you see anything else in the logs when the twincat tries to connect?

Can you please expand the "Valuer" column in your screenshot so we can see the full value of eConnectionState (or, even better, add this as text in your question).

The client SPD its just a name I give to my broker. And I can give you the screenshot monday when I go to work, I give you an extended version of the value.

I edit the post and add the expanded version of the result of 'fbMqttClient'. And when I try to connect to twincat, I don't have any logs other than what I'm already sending. thank you for you'r reply.
